# AJAX response: sugestions for JSON format?

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, json

Say I submit a form via Ajax and need a response from the server:

- Pass/fail indicator
- On fail, a list of validation errors with associated field ids/names, etc

Is there a standard or best practice for the JSON format for such a structure? If so, I'd like to try to stick to it instead of coming up with my own convention.

Comment: I have never heard of a standard format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
    "result": "false", 
    "fields":
        [
             {"id": "element1", "name": "element1"},
             {"id": "element2", "name": "element2"},
             {"id": "element3", "name": "element3"}
        ]
}
```

Comment: I recommend a different structure where it's "messages" rather than "fields" and each object within that collection possibly has a field associated with it. Not every message returned from the server (whether error message, success message, or otherwise) will be associated with a "field".

Answer (score 6):

OmniTI has a decent standard that I like and recommend: http://labs.omniti.com/labs/jsend

```
{
    status : "success",
    data : {
        "posts" : [
            { "id" : 1, "title" : "A blog post", "body" : "Some useful content" },
            { "id" : 2, "title" : "Another blog post", "body" : "More content" },
        ]
     }
}
```

I usually use a variant:

```
{
    status : "error",
    messages : {
        "some_field" : "message"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an OLD question but worth an update. Nowadays I'm a fan of JSON:API for purely JSON-based structured, self-descriptive, resource-oriented APIs. If you consider your form request as creating a resource, whatever it might be, then JSON:API (just the basics) gives you a decent foundation to build a more complex API onto.

Answer (score 2):

Peter Bui's got this proposal format:  http://paydrotalks.com/posts/45-standard-json-response-for-rails-and-jquery

```
{
  status: "ok|redirect|error",
  to: "http://www.redirect-url.com",
  html: "<b>Insert html</b>",
  message: "Insert some message here"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. I don't know about a standard, but you might want to just do something like

```
{
    "result": "false",
    "errors":
        [
             {"errorCode": "1234", "errorText": "malformed address"},
             {"errorCode": "5678", "errorText": "no username"}
        ]
}
```

Comment: it's something we do at work. I'm not sure of the reasoning myself :P I'm assuming it's for a general validation failure case, to which no specific errors map....but then again, that would seem to merit a catchall error code. I'm not sure why they do it :)

Comment: imho its redundant and not fault-tolerance. checking if the error-array has values before accessing them is imho in such cases necessary. otherwise you have to handle exception in accessing

Comment: Yah. True. I'd added a comment about the redundancy before, but I'll just remove the hasErrors flag.